# Any way to disable ctrl-alt-delete in windows 8.1 “assigned access” (kiosk) mode?

Tags: kiosk, windows-8.1

We are evaluating using the Windows 8.1 "assigned access" mode to set up a kiosk application for a building lobby. I've got the RTM running on a virtual machine and am shocked to discover that, while it does force the user into the one program and keep him or her there, this mode does *not* seem to intercept ctrl-alt-delete! I can send the machine a ctrl-alt-delete and am brought to a page that would allow me to:

- Log out
- Log in as another user
- Change the kiosk account password (if  the original password was known)
- Shutdown
- Reboot
- Change accessibility settings

This seems like such a huge flaw in a mode intended for kiosk applications that I'm wondering if I'm just missing something. Is it just assumed that when you're running a kiosk the keyboard would not be attached? Is it an artifact of running under a virtual machine? Is there some way to keep it from reacting to ctrl-alt-del?

Comment: There has to be a group policy for this...only the a few of those is a pain unless you have software to roll back all changes.  How are you sending the key command exactly through software or hardware?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Kalhas notes, you can create a GPO. To create a local group policy, on the system in question, run "GPEDIT.MSC".  Under User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System, you will see "Ctrl-Alt-Del Options".  You can configure any or all of the 4 policies:
Remove Change Password
Remove Lock Computer
Remove Task Manager
Remove Logoff

Combined, these effectively take the teeth out of Ctrl-Alt-Del.

User switching is disabled in a different location in Group Policy Editor:
Local Computer Policy> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon
Choose "Hide Entry Points for Fast User Switching" to change Fast User Switching policy setting.
If these systems are joined to your domain, you can alternately centrally manage this policy at the domain level.

Answer (score 1):

Kiosk or not, you can create a Group Policy Object on your domain to restrict such behavior; an alternative would be to create a local group policy.

Option A gives an option to rollback. Option B you have to create records of your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  While your answer is correct, I accepted Debra's because she walked me through the details (which was very helpful).